# TypeScript challenge - additional fields to object

Tags: javascript, typescript, compiler-errors, interface

On a TypeScript project when a `repository` method retrieves a well-defined class instance with important fields. The 'domain' layer post-process the entities, tries to flag them storing the flag value on a field `isVIP` which is not part of the class instance:

```
interface IUser { name:string, email:string }
let users: IUser[] = this.userRepository.getAll();
for(const user of users)
{
  if (......) user.isVIP = true;
}
```

The TypeScript compiler says (which is true):

> error TS2339: Property 'isVIP ' does not exist on type 'IUser'.

I understand and accept the reason why: but for later processing the `users` collection it is a nice way to add this flag to the collection items. We cannot modify the well defined User class adding this field to this as it is used only for this operation.

I wonder what is the best way to add this field somehow to these entities? The `user["isVip"] = true` looks so ... different, and dirty for me. A hope a more elegant solution exists somewhere :)

Comment: You could create another type `type FlaggedUser = IUser & {isVIP: boolean}`, then instead of assigning to `isVIP` you do `const flaggedUsers = users.map<FlaggedUser>(user => ({...user, isVIP: (...) }))`. If you don't want to create another type or modify `IUser`, I don't have much to advise, it will basically be a combo of bad practices: mutating data and circumventing the type system, a sure way to disaster in the future. At that point you can just use type casts or `any`, any solution will be a dirty hack, because this is against the type system

Comment: I would second the type VipUser that adds this field.  I also kinda feel like you want to partition into two lists here,  one for normalUsers and one for vipUsers.  In fact, that would get you out of having to modify the type at all.

Comment: Please consider providing a [mre] that we can paste into our own IDEs to see what you're seeing; that will mean everyone's on the same page and nobody has to guess about what `this` or `userRepository` might be, for example.